# Structure of $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt {2i})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, notation

Let $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt {2i})$. My guess would be a field with elements of the form $a+b\sqrt 2i$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$. But the last option suggests that it is a vector space. Do not need hints about the solution yet.

Let
$$F = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i}).$$

Which of the following is *not* true?

(A) $\sqrt{2} \in F$

(B) $i\in F$

(C) $x^8-16=0$ has a solution in $F$

(D) $\dim_{\Bbb{Q}}(F)=2$

Comment: I think it's $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^2=2i$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So a field with elements of the form $a+b\sqrt {2i}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$. Then what is its dimension of a field, see last option?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm only aware of the dimension of a vector space. How do you define the dimension of a field?

Comment: a field extension is a vector space over the subfield; the dimension is how many elements in a basis, just like any other vector space

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^2=2i$.  Then $\alpha^4=(2i)^2=-4,$ so

$\alpha$ is a root of $x^4+4=(x^2+2)^2-4x^2=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2).$

Elements of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ can be expressed as $q_1+q_2\alpha$ with $q_1,q_2,\in\mathbb Q$

$(\alpha^2 $ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $1$), so $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=2.$

Comment: $x^4 + 4 = (x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$ and is thus not irreducible, and therefore isn't the miminal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler:  thanks so much for pointing that out; I have tried to correct my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$(1+i)^2 = 1 + 2i -1 = 2i,$$
hence
$$1+i = \sqrt{2i}.$$
Therefore $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i})=\Bbb{Q}(1+i)$. Let $\alpha := 1+i$. The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is 
$$p(x)=x^2-2x +2,$$
which has degree $2$, hence
$$\dim_{\Bbb{Q}}(F)=2.$$
Also notice that
$$i=-1 + \alpha  \in \Bbb{Q}(\alpha).$$
Furthermore
$$x^{8}-16 = (x^4-4)(x^4+4)$$
and $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4+4$, since
$$\alpha^4 + 4 = (1+i)^4 + 4 = -4+4=0$$
Therefore, by exclusion **the wrong statement is**:
$$\sqrt{2} \in F$$