# Let $F=Q(\sqrt{2i})$,then

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$F=Q(\sqrt{2i})$,then
Which one of the following is not true (Duet-2017 Q.26)

1.$\sqrt{2}\in F$

2.$i \in F$

3.$x^8-16=0$ has a solution in $F$

4.$dim_Q(F)=2$

I thought it as $F=${$a+b(\sqrt{2i})| a,b \in Q$}

from which it implies $\sqrt{2} \notin F$ and $\sqrt{2i}$ is a solution of $x^8-16=0$

I didn't get about what about dimensions
And I thought $i \notin F$ but answer has only one solution which is option 1.

Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: If something, then… Then what?! Fix the title.

Comment: What does “Duet-2017” mean?

Comment: The number $\sqrt{2i}$ is *not* quadratic over the rationals, so $F$ is not just the $\mathbf Q$-linear combinations of $1$ and $\sqrt{2i}$.

Comment: For the exact same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277153/structure-of-f-mathbb-q-sqrt-2i?rq=1).

Comment: @KCd - The number $\sqrt{2i}=1+\sqrt{-1}$ is quadratic over the rationals.

Comment: @mr_e_man  ah, whoops!  I was thinking for typical $b$ that $\sqrt{bi}$ is quartic over $\mathbf Q$, not the specific case $b=2$.

Answer (score 2):

First take a look at what $\sqrt{i}$ can be. From elementary complex analysis you have $\sqrt{2i}=\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=1+i$ .

Note that we are only considering $\sqrt{i}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and but we can also take it to be $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ .  In any case we would get that it is $\Bbb{Q}(1+i)=\Bbb{Q}(i)$ .

Now it is clear from above that $\sqrt{2}\notin \Bbb{Q}(i)$ and $i\in\Bbb{Q}(i)$. Also $\dim(F)=2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ as it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^{2}+1)$ as a field . Also look that you can take $\sqrt{2i}$ to be a root of either of the irreducible polynomials $x^{2}-2x+2$ or $x^{2}+2x+2$ . This just means that $\{1,\sqrt{2i}\}$ or $\{1,i\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i})=\Bbb{Q}(i)$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. Now to prove these things, you would need to say what kind of field theory you have been introduced to. If you just know $\Bbb{F}(\alpha)=\{a_{0}+a_{1}\alpha+...+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}\}$ where $\alpha$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ of degree $n$ , then you can directly see that $\{1,\sqrt{2i}\}$ or $\{1,i\}$ is a basis . Otherwise you'll need a more formal and precise argument. You have define it to be $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^{2}-2x+2)$ and then use a canonical isomorphism to $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i})$ .

The whole thing depends on what definition you use for $\sqrt{2i}$ as $\sqrt{z}$ is a multiple valued function. Usually in such cases, the polynomial which the above root satisfies is given so that you can identify it to be one root of it . But in this case, you have to make an assumption that either $\sqrt{2i}=1+i$ or $\sqrt{2i}=-(1+i)$ and carry on using basic complex analysis.

$\sqrt{2i}$ is a solution for $x^{8}-16$ .

Answer (score 1):

1. Is false, in case it's true we would have $F(\sqrt2)=F$, but
   $$F(\sqrt2)=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{2i},\sqrt 2)}=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt i,\sqrt 2)}\not =\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{2i})}=F$$
2. Similar argument
3. Is true
   $$(\sqrt{2i})^8=16$$
4. True
   The dimension of a field extension is just the dimension of the extension as a vector field over the base field. Its easy to prove that if we have an extension generated by an algebraic number, the dimension will be the degree of its minimal polynomial over the field so:
   $$dim_{\mathbb{Q}}(F)=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2i}):\mathbb{Q}]=deg(P_{min\;\sqrt{2i}}(t))=deg(t^2-2t+2)=2$$

Comment: I would like to know Why the down votes...

Comment: exactly man. The question also does not merit downvotes.

Comment: $t^{2}+2$ is not the minimal polynomial . It is the minimal polynomial for $i\sqrt{2}$. The minimal polynomial should be $x^{2}-2x+2$ or $x^{2}+2x+2$ depending upon which value of the multiple valued function $\sqrt{z}$ you choose to be as $\sqrt{2i}$ .

Comment: Ups that's true. What a mis take, thanks!

Comment: I think the op does not know the formal construction of how to "attach roots" . He says that he does not have idea about how to calculate the dimension.